IHttpContextAccessor: IsAuthenticated always false
I'm building a .NET8 web app with a REST API where I'm trying to check if the requesting user is an admin to execute different code paths based on that but for some reason the code which is supposed to check it always returns false.
The controller method:
[HttpPut]
[Route("api/vehicle")]
[SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.Accepted)]
public async Task<IActionResult> VehicleModify([FromBody] VehicleModel vehicleModel)
{
    bool userIsAdmin = JwtMiddleware.IsUserInRoleForHttpContext(_httpContextAccessor, "Admin");

    if (!userIsAdmin)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("VehicleModify {@Plate}", vehicleModel.Plate);
        return Unauthorized();
    }

    if (vehicleModel == null)
        return BadRequest();

    await _vehicleService.Modify(vehicleModel);
    return Accepted();
}

The IsUserInRoleForHttpContext() method:
public static bool IsUserInRoleForHttpContext(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, string roleName)
{
    var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;

    if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // IsAuthenticated always false
        return false;

    return user.IsInRole(roleName);
}

So apparently:
httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

is always false.
What am I doing wrong?

Do you have an [Authorize] attribute on your controller?

Yes, I do have the attribute.

Have you checked if maybe your host's configuration missing or having misplaced UseAuthentication() method?
Remember that UseAuthentication() method, which adds authentication middleware, should be located before the other middleware, which processes the incoming web request by creating and invoking controller methods.
builder.ConfigureApplication(app =>
{
    app.UseHealth("/health");

    app.UseAuthentication(); // This should exist and be BEFORE MapControllers.

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization(); // Same goes for this, altho this needs to be AFTER auth, obviously.

    app.MapControllers();
});

This is required so that the auth middleware could process the request and fill in all the necessary auth data (for instance httpContext.User) before any controller methods are invoked.
Also remember to have that authentication set up, for instance, via adding authentication schemes. For you, I suppose, that would be some kind of JWT/bearer auth.
